# Find the roots of $p(X)= x^5- x^4- 3x^2+ x^2 +3$

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Find roots for Polynomial $p(X)= x^5- x^4- 3x^2+ x^2 +3$.

The given answer is $x = -2,-1,0,1,2$.

However, I've been getting $x=-3, -1, 0 ,1,3$. Thus is it possible to get different sets of answer for polynomial, or have I  been doing it wrong?

Comment: Please check the edit and make necessary changes. Are you sure about the expression of the polynomial? In this form $0$ is not a root, as $p(0)=3 \neq 0$.

Comment: Is the formula of $P$ correct? $P(0)=3$ so $0$ is not a root!

Comment: There are two $x^2$ terms in your polynomial. And as pointed out by many users your roots seem to be also wrong.

Comment: Best idea would be for you to add *into your question post*, the work you've done that led you to what you are "getting".

Answer (score 2):

Let's check:

$p(0)=0^5-0^4-3\cdot 0^2+0^2+3=3\neq 0\implies 0$ is not a root.

$p(-1)-...=-1\neq 0\implies -1$ is not a root.

$p(-2)=...=-53\neq  0\implies -2$ is not a root.

And so on.

You can try with [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)

See also [WA's](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5-x%5E4-3x%5E2%2Bx%5E2%2B3) result.